# How create a listener to a attribute service in grails

Tags: grails, listener

I have a problem. I am programming a grails application and I want create a listener to determinate attribute on my service class that I use it on my controller. When this attribute changes I want that the controller be notified. Someone can give a tip or the way to do this? The pseudo-code controller and service are bellow.

```
class myController{

    def someService

    def index() {
        def return = someService.doSomething();
        render (template: "template")
    }
}
```

My Service

```
class myService {

    private void doSomething(){

        //some code here changing the variable to be listened
        ...
        ...
    }

}
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking for here. You'll need to be more specific.

Comment: you can define an interface between the service and controller and pass it as a callback from the controller to the service. I.e when something happens the service will call a method on the callback passed.

Comment: What do you want the controller to do after the service has told it the value has changed?